# R instability with high numbers of ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, bigdata

#### Background

I'm trying to generate a whopping ton of histogram plots (about 100) by using ggplot and [this multiplot function](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/). `multiplot` takes a list of plots as its main argument, so I generate a list:

```
plotlist <- lapply(mycolnames[1:num_plots],function(names) {
    ggplot(mydata, aes_string(x=names, fill="Class")) + geom_density(alpha=.3)
  })
```

Each column has 98000 points, and there are as many columns as `num_plots`. This works for `num_plots=10`, but R died on `50`. Unfortunately, RStudio didn't expose the trace, so I can't tell if it was a memory issue. (I have 8GB to work with on a Linux server.)

I see a few ways of tackling this: I could randomly sample rows, or I could put this in a loop that does 10 at a time. Is there a general approach to handling this amount of data that I can default to?

#### Object sizes

Following Martín's suggestion, I split off one plot and then looked at the larger list:

```
> object.size(p1)
4683224 bytes
> object.size(plotlist) # here 30 plots, approximately 30x memory
140,497,000 bytes
```

This is for 4900 sampled points. For the full 98000, it looks like this:

```
> object.size(p1)
92,922,432 bytes
```

30 times that would be about 2.5GB. So it looks like I'm running into a memory ceiling.

Interestingly, I seem to be limited to much less than the available RAM. How should I adjust that?

```
> gc()
            used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   1879639  100.4    3094291  165.3   3094291  165.3
Vcells 141384288 1078.7  365457852 2788.3 476322412 3634.1
```

#### OS limits

`ulimit` reports no limits on physical memory, which makes me wonder where this R session is getting its limits from.

Comment: assign one plot to an object and check out how much memmory R allocates for each ggplot object. e.g. ```p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = l)) + geom_jitter() + facet_grid(. ~ l)``` RStudio provides this information in the right window.

Comment: Save your plot as png files Then read them , 4 by 4..

Comment: You could try a slightly different method of laying out multiple ggplots and see if that works. Here's an option from Hadley's ggplot2 wiki using grid.arrange from the gridExtra package (see the second heading): https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Mixing-ggplot2-graphs-with-other-graphical-output

Comment: That looks good and is definitely more portable; it looks like my main problem is storing the plot info before even rendering it.

Comment: In terms of memory usage, a good rule of thumb is that an analysis uses three times the dataset size as RAM due to copying of objects.

Comment: I would do the calculations done by `stat_density` outside of ggplot2. This could then be optimized for memory efficiency.

Comment: RAM size can be a bit of a red herring. You will often be limited by the amount of contiguous virtual memory available to the OS. And I'm assuming you are using the 64-bit version of R. Anyway, the problem is that each plot needs its own copy of your data. Perhaps using a `data.table` to store `mydata` will yield some memory reduction.